# How to create vector of strings in javascript (TypeScript) Flatbuffers?

Tags: javascript, typescript, flatbuffers

is there any way how to create vector of strings in TypeScript?
I already tried lot of things but nothing worked.

I evean tried to created "covering tabel in schema StringArray" like this:

> table StringArray {   items:[string]; }

And I'm trying to use it like this:

```
let builder: flatbuffers.Builder = new flatbuffers.Builder();


let offsets : Array<flatbuffers.Offset>;
offsets = new Array<flatbuffers.Offset>(2);

offsets[0] = builder.createString("hello");
offsets[1] = builder.createString("world");

let offsetOfStrings = messaging.StringArray.createItemsVector(builder, offsets);

// create message
messaging.StringArray.startStringArray(builder);
messaging.StringArray.addItems(builder, offsetOfStrings);
let serialized = messaging.Message.endMessage(builder);

builder.finish(serialized);
let data = builder.asUint8Array();
```

But is it right way? Isnt`t there something like right better and shorter way ?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is going wrong? The code on first glance looks correct.

Comment: Yes, the code I presented works fine, my english is not best sorry. :) The right question is: Isnt`t there something like right way to do this ? I feel this is not right.

Comment: What makes you feel it's not right? Yes, it's a bit complicated API, but it tries to be efficient (build data in-place).